# No suitable JDBC Excel driver is found in exported runnable .jar file

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, xlsx

I've written J2SE application that uses connections with Excel spreadsheet and Oracle. I'm using `xlsjdbc-1.7.0.jar` drivers for Excel connections.

It runs fine from Eclipse, but when I build a runnable `.jar` file and try to execute it on other PC, it shows following error:

[No suitable Driver found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kPx7.png)

Comment: Did you remember to supply the JDBC .jar file, **and** to put it on the classpath?

Comment: I thought, .jars apis are added in .jar package when extracted.

Comment: No they are not, unless you build a fat-jar, which - in my opinion - is a bad practice.

Comment: Plase share your directory structure and commandline you use for "execute it on other pc" - it#s most likely a classpath thing.

Comment: I'm using the root directory for all files. i.e. the connection file and spreadsheet to be operationed. Here is the command to run my .jar
java -jar MyJarFile.jar
(whiling being in root directory in cmd)

Comment: So isn't there anyone to ans? Problem is still pending..